# Overflowing Parent <div> in nested CSS

Tags: html, css

I managed to overflow a parent div which is a content wrapper with the following CSS, however now this div hides content behind it. How can I do this right?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YMSvU/

**My HTML File**

```
<div class="contentwrapper">
  <div class="promotional_outer">
    <div class="promotional">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  ... this footer is overflown by the promotional div ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**My CSS File**

```
.contentwrapper {
    width: 1150px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.promotional_outer{
    background-color: #8fcbe5;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    clear: both;
}
.promotional {
    background-color: #30a3da;
    padding: 75px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    clear: both;
}
```

[image: This explains the issue]

Comment: That's the whole point of overflowing, what exactly do you want to happen? Do you want the footer to appear above the overflowing div?

Comment: Why do you position `.promotional_outer` absolute, instead of relative (default)?

Comment: I positioned promotional_outer absolute with left 0 so I would overflow the parent. The promotional_outer should be 100% of the screen width rather than only 1150 pixels wide. then the promptional is normal again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had *exactly* the same problem on a site I'm working on at the moment.

Turns out the only solution is to do it like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="promotion_outer">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="promotion_inner">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works for me if I use absoulte position and left 0, however then the following content items are hidden. I assume I have to change it, like you said, even though I dont like that ...

Comment: all you can do is use a fixed height, or use javascript to find the height of the inner and apply to the outer, or do it how I'm doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to adjust your html to do something like this:

```
<div class="inner">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class="promo">
    <div class="promo--inner">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="promo--callout">
        <p>Promo callout</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="inner  footer">
    <p>Footer content</p>
</div>
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kFShb/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the element's flow by using `z-index`.

```
.footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMSvU/2/)

Comment: Yet in the fiddle it does? You must be hiding something... Try increasing the z-index.

Comment: I added this to the footer, check out http://goo.gl/Ae4VK and add position:absolute; left: 0; to promotional_outer and position: relative; z-index: 10; you will see the issue then.

Comment: [this code](http://pastebin.com/dyvwYVQ9) produces [this result](http://d.pr/i/JN9O) - it's a matter of moving stuff around.

Comment: I see, however the footer is still not below the blue box as it is supposed to be ...

Comment: You can increase the promotional_outer's margin-bottom to a big amount and it'll make more space for the footer to reach lower down without going outside the page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute` from `.promotional_outer`.

Absolute positioning *removes* an element from the normal document flow.

Comment: If I remove position: absolute and left:0 the error is solved, however now I dont overflow my parent contentwrapper anymore, which I did with this solution.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish then? Could you clarify?

Comment: I have uploaded a picture to the original post, that may clarify what I am indending.

Comment: Great - thx for the pic. Just a note, overflow has a very specific meaning for css, which is what caused everyone to be confused here. I think you are going to have to change the html

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `position: absolute;` and `left: 0;` in your CSS

```
.promotional_outer{
    background-color: #8fcbe5;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    clear: both;
}
```

[This should solve your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/YMSvU/3/).

Comment: If I remove position: absolute and left:0 the error is solved, however now I dont overflow my parent contentwrapper anymore, which I did with this solution.